# Storing php get value inside ajax data

Tags: php, ajax

I have like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    var n = $('<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>').val();
    var e = $('<?php echo $_GET['email'];?>').val();

$.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "file.php",
                        data: {name: n, email: e},
                        success: function(status) {
                            $('#result').append(status);

                        }
                    });

    });
    </script>
```

Why does it store empty values inside `e` and `n`?

And inside `file.php` when I echo em they are empty.

But here when I echo `$_GET['name']` or email it show real values?

Thanks

Comment: Where's "here" in "But here when I echo ..."?

Comment: in the file with these code where are GET values

Comment: `var n = '<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>';
    var e = '<?php echo $_GET['email'];?>';`

Answer (score 0):

you have a mistake in your code. you have to store that variable like below.

```
var n = '<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>';
var e = '<?php echo $_GET['email'];?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it store empty values inside e and n?

My guess is that jQuery isn't finding the matching elements you're looking for.  For example, if I go to your page with this:

```
page.php?name=David
```

Then that code will emit this:

```
var n = $('David').val();
```

That jQuery selector would be looking for this:

```
<David />
```

Which *probably* doesn't exist on that page.  (With an email address it would be even stranger.)

If you want to store the values themselves in a JavaScript variable, you don't need any jQuery for that:

```
var n = '<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>';
```

If, on the other hand, the `$_GET['name']` value is supposed to be the *name of the HTML input* and you want to use jQuery to find that input, it would be more like this:

```
var n = $('input[name=<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>]').val();
```

It's not entirely clear if that's what you're looking to do, though.  Depends on what you expect `$_GET['name']` to contain.

You can confirm all of this using the debugging tools in your browser.  (Usually opened by pressing F12.)  Examine the page source client-side (*after* the PHP code has been processed) to see what your JavaScript is actually doing, look at the jQuery selector(s) you're trying to build, debug the JavaScript to see if the target elements are found, etc.